# creating the addins in EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

We are creating the addin for EA.So is there any Prerequisites for creating the addin for EA 12.1 that it should be created using Visual studio 2013 ultimate. Or Can the addins for EA 12.1 can also be created in the Visual studio 2013 community Edition.

Comment: I use Sharpdevelop for all my add-ins.

Answer (score 3):

An Add-In is deployed as a DLL. So as long as the VS edition supports DLL projects, you'll be fine. If it also supports some way to create an installer, eg WiX, that helps too.

EA's Interop DLL is the only library (outside the regular Windows platform) you need, and Add-Ins can be written in any environment and language which supports COM. .NET and C# is the most common, but you could write an Add-In in C++ if you wished.